# Запрос на изменение не завершается в течении 9 часов в Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Вот собственно сам запрос:

```
update acs_event
    set institution = t2.institution_id
    from acs_event t1
    LEFT JOIN "acs_controller"
        ON (t1."controller_id" = "acs_controller"."id")
    JOIN "acs_building" t2
        ON ("acs_controller"."building_id" = t2."id");
```

В таблице 4 млн строк.
Работает уже более 9 часов.
Кто сталкивался с таким? Может я что то не так делаю?

Аналогичный select завершается за 7 сек.

```
select t1.institution, t2.institution_id
    from acs_event t1
             LEFT JOIN "acs_controller"
                       ON (t1."controller_id" = "acs_controller"."id")
             JOIN "acs_building" t2
                  ON ("acs_controller"."building_id" = t2."id");
```

Comment: *`LEFT JOIN "acs_controller"`* А зачем LEFT JOIN? всё одно последующий JOIN превращает его в INNER...

Comment: А нет ли у вас каких-то триггеров, под которые подпадает такое изменение? Индексы тоже могут несколько тормозить. А вообще какой процент записей реально не совпадает и нуждается в обновлении; а то может сравнивать на неравенство и обновлять только не совпадающие, а не все подряд?

Comment: обновить нужно все записи, бо добавил новое поле и как раз его надо обновить.

Comment: Индексы, констрейнты, триггеры на это новое поле какие-то есть? Можно попробовать всё что есть отключить на время обновления. Или может есть какие-то триггеры на эту таблицу в целом?

Comment: Надо было селект выполнить в CTE (добавив `acs_event.id`), и оттуда обновиться.

Comment: Тригеров нет. Индексы есть, но они не затрагивают это поле.
Что такое CTE?

Comment: *Что такое CTE?* [WITH Queries (Common Table Expressions)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас проверяю такой запрос:
with q1 as (
    select t1.id, t2.institution_id
    from acs_event t1
             LEFT JOIN "acs_controller"
                       ON (t1."controller_id" = "acs_controller"."id")
             JOIN "acs_building" t2
                  ON ("acs_controller"."building_id" = t2."id")
)
update acs_event
    set institution=q1.institution_id
    from q1
        where acs_event.id=q1.id;

Comment: Прошло 10 мин с момента запуска.
Поведение системы немного изменилось:
- процессор нагружен гораздо сильнее
- лампочка диска практически горит красным

Comment: Помогло. Запрос выполнился за 13 мин.
Спасибо.